# php: Create an array with ascending date objects

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I would like to create an array which consists of ascending date objects. I tried the following code:

```
$dat=date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2014-11-01 00:00:00");
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
    $ar[$i]=$dat;
    $dat->modify('+1 day');
}
print_r($ar);
```

The result is three times the same date:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-11-04 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
        )

    [1] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-11-04 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
        )

    [2] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-11-04 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
        )

)
```

But what I would like to get is:

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2014-11-01 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
            )

        [1] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2014-11-02 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
            )

        [2] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2014-11-03 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
            )

    )
```

Someone has an idea? Probably a newbie-thing ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$dat` is an obejct, all items in `$ar` store references to this object. So, when this object changes (`$dat->modify()`), all references immediately see this changes. To create different object, you can `clone` source object:

```
$dat = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2014-11-01 00:00:00");
for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    $ar[$i] = clone $dat;
    $dat->modify('+1 day');
}
print_r($ar);
```

Here `clone` operator takes you current `$dat` object and makes a copy of it. So when you change `$dat` again, copy doesn't know about it.